# How to verify the each element in json is in-line with schema

Tags: json, go, json-schema-validator

I am able to validate my.json with my-schema.json(basically it do structure level verification).
But if we want to check each element is of correct type as specified in schema json??

Comment: in which programming language do you need the solution . ??

Comment: I looking in golang